# Changing content of a hidden Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

Is there a way of manipulating content of a Word document that is opened as invisible? Most of the functions exposed by the DOM for manipulating document content (such as `InsertFile` that I need to use) reside in `Selection` object. For visible document, the normal course of action is to first call `Doc.Activate` to move selection into that document and then use `Selection` object to manipulate it. How can the `Selection` object for invisible documents?

If you're interested, `Documents.Open` and `Documents.Add` functions allow you to open or create a document without showing it on screen. Just call it like this:

```
this.Application.Documents.Open(Visible: false);    
this.Application.Documents.Add(Visible: false);
```

I'm using VSTO, but if you know the answer in VBA, just let me know, since VSTO is mostly compliant with VBA DOM.

Comment: Actually it is better to avoid use of the Selection object in the majority of cases and use the Range object instead. As InsertFile is also a method of the Range object, you can use it so long as you can identify the location in the document that you need.

Comment: I'll second Timothy's comment. The Range object will let you do whatever you need to a hidden document, with a little creativity and research. The Selection object is  far less reliable and not useable at all on a hidden document.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: Thank you guys. Having working with VBA and VSTO for over 20 years, it is such a shame that I could think of this straight-forward thing. Feeling like the Naughty Boy of John Keats: *...So he stood in his shoes, And he wondered, He wondered, He stood in his shoes, And he wondered."*